# Can't connect to SQL Server 1433 port for VM windows server externally on gcloud

Tags: sql-server, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have already enabled the port in the firewall rules in gcloud, windows server and instance. I defined the port in the sql configuration manager. The other ports like 8080, 23, 21 are working normally. Only port 1433 is not working.

Comment: Does netstat show the system is listening on 1433?

Comment: What is the error your get? Connection refused? No route to host?